# Can not run exe in Win 10 that build in win 7 by visual stadio 12?

Tags: c#

I created a program in Win 7 by visual studio 12. In my program, I import a dll c++ and load that dll. After built to exe, it run in Win 7 but when i copy to computer that installed win 10, my program can not run and notify that" can not load abc.dll".

Comment: Error message is pretty clear. Your program needs `abc.dll` to run.

Comment: In the computer that installed win 7, it work normally, but in win 10, it not work. I do not understand why it can not load that dll?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think that you should be change the name of library to abcd.dll instead of abc.dll. Good Luck!